# .htaccess RewriteRule html and txt files

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

this is my htacces file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It's work ok but I have one question. If I add to my page files for google in example with .html or .txt i can't see it in browser... How I can change that rule that I could see files from google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid rewriting for all files/direcotries:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```